# Passing ID to Django URL

Tags: django

Good day Stack Overflow;

I want to use a url to access data from database base on the data's ID. I know there are duplicates of the same question here on SO but I cant seem to figure out something so basic. Hope you can help me with this.

Everything works out except on my template.

if I pass the url as:

```
<a href="{% url 'job_details' 5 %}">
```

It will get the Job with ID of 5. But if I use

```
<!--- <a href="{% url 'job_details' PropositionItem.id %}"> --->
<!--- 2nd href fixes the details --->
<a href="{% url 'job_details' id=jobItems.id %}">
```

It will return

```
Reverse for 'job_details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['jobs/details/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']
```

as Error Message.

My Model is something like this:

```
class PropositionItem(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('users.Account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', null=False)
```

urls.py

```
path('details/<int:id>', views.job_details, name='job_details'),
```

views.py

```
def job_details(request, id, *args, **kwargs):

context = {}
jobObj = PropositionItem.objects.get(id=id)
job_form = PropositionItemForm(
                                initial = {
                                    "job_title" : jobObj.job_title,
                                }
                            )
context['job_form'] = job_form

return render(request, 'jobs/job_form.html', context)
```

What should I write on my href?

**EDIT**

My detailsView right now changes with different ID. But my ListView is returning the same error message.

listView

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def job_list(request, *args, **kwargs):

    context = {}
    jobItems = PropositionItem.objects.all().filter(created_by=request.user)
    context={
      'jobItems': jobItems
    }
    
    return render(request, 'jobs/job_list.html', context)
```

listURL

```
path('', views.job_list, name='job_list'),
```

Comment: show the view function which is redering your template

Comment: Yes. I added it now.

Comment: I asked for the view that renders `<a href="{% url 'job_details' PropositionItem.id %}">` but you showed the view of `job_details`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are not assigning the ID value, could you try

```
id=PropositionItem.id
```

Comment: same error message for the code `<a href="{% url 'job_details' id=PropositionItem.id %}">`

Comment: could you display the id in your html page to ensure it is appearing and it is an int

Comment: Thank you for answering. Right now my detailsView is working properly. Can access different data with different ID. Right now though, my ListView is returning the same error message.